# How to share data across several android apps

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've several android apps published on Google Play store. I want to generate my custom id to identify a device, that should be shared across my all apps. I'm thinking to create a custom content provider that can generate the custom id to be shared across all my apps. Is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, if you are storing data that needs to be shared between your suite of apps, then the custom content provider is the way to go.

If all you need is a global device identifier, please review this answer for a unique ID to use:
[Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)